# Angular Dependancy Injection

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a quick question about Angular Dependancy Injection. I have read that if you want a service to have only a single instance across your app, it should be included as a provider in the AppModule instead of any components that use it. Would this still apply other modules imported by the AppModule. For example, I want to have an AuthService as a provider in my SharedModule. If I then import this module to the AppModule, would all the components across my app share the same instance of the service?

Comment: Please describe your question in the title.

Comment: I didn't really know how to.

Comment: yes, all modules except for the lazy loaded add providers to the root injector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes

but..

> Do not specify app-wide singleton providers in a shared module. A lazy-loaded module that imports that shared module makes its own copy of the service.

Source: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#why-userservice-isnt-shared

Comment: I see, because the SharedModule might be imported multiple times, there would be multiple instances of the AuthModule. Where as in the CoreModule, it would only be imported once. Right?

Comment: @user455289 yes exaclty but only if these modules are lazy loaded. If not, it will work it seems but it is not recommended. If something is not recommended in angular docs you should consider it because they might change it in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the NgModule imports/exports to enforce a singleton pattern. As pointed out by echonax's answer lazy loaded modules bootstrap all services again.

With that said, you can block duplicate imports on a module via the constructor. This will force the developer to manage the module load order, and also prevent a lazy module from importing it directly. If the module is imported by a secondary module it appears to get around this problem.

You can block like this in your NgModule class constructor

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        MySingletonService
    ]
})
export class ExampleModule {
    public constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: ExampleModule) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error('ExampleModule is already loaded');
        }
    }
}
```

It's best to create modules that have just one service in them, and not use them for anything else. That makes it much easier to manage the kinds of dependencies.